# Substitute for annatto seeds in Achiote Paste

Tags: substitutions

I am making Achiote Paste and need a substitute for the annatto seeds.  Recipe calls for 1/4 cup of annatto seeds.  Can I substitute tumeric, saffron or paprika and if so how much should I use?

Comment: In addition to the duplicate, google "achiote paste substitute" for a recipe from the website "Epicurious."